# Using textureGrad for anisotropic integration approximation

Tags: opengl, cubemap, mipmaps, filtering, pbr

I'm trying to develop a real time rendering method using real time acquired envmap (cubemap) for lightning.

This implies that my envmap can change as often as every frame and I therefore cannot use any method base on precomputation of the envmap (such as convolution with BRDF...)

So far my method worked well with Phong BRDF. For specular contribution I direclty read the value in my sampleCube and I use mipmap levels + linear filter for simulating the roughtness of the material considered:

```
int size                = textureSize(envmap, 0).x;
float specular_level    = log2(size * sqrt(3.0)) - 0.5 * log2(ns + 1);
vec3 env_specular       = ks * specular_color * textureLod(envmap, l_g, specular_level);
```

From this method I would like to upgrade to a microfacet based BRDF. I already have algorithm for evaluating the shape (including anisotropic direction) of the reflection but I cannot manage to read the values I want in my sampleCube.

I believe I have to use

```
textureGrad(envmap, l_g, X, Y);
```

with l_g being the reflection direction in global space but I cannot manage to find which values to give to X and Y in order to correctly specify the area I want to consider.

What value should I give to X and Y in orther for

```
textureGrad(envmap, l_g, X, Y);
```

to give the same result as

```
textureLod(envmap, l_g, specular_level);
```

Comment: I thinked a convolution in compute shader a relatively cheap, there possible use stohastic sampling also.

Answer (score 2):

The gradient values are normally (when you do a standard texture lookup) the screen-space derivatives of the texture coordinates, `dFdx(l_g), dFdy(l_g)`.

In order to do anisotropic filtering while also specifying the base mip level as `specularLevel`, you could try rescaling the derivatives so the length of the smaller derivative is `pow(2.0, specularLevel)`.  You want to maintain the relationship between the two derivatives so that the aniso filter has the same shape.  Something like this:

```
vec3 derivX = dFdx(l_g);
vec3 derivY = dFdy(l_g);
float minLength = sqrt(min(dot(derivX, derivX), dot(derivY, derivY)));
float desiredLength = pow(2.0, specularLevel);
float scale = desiredLength / minLength;
derivX *= scale;
derivY *= scale;
... textureGrad(envmap, l_g, derivX, derivY);
```

Comment: I tried rescaling those simple derivative (basically i'll, at some point, have to rotate derivX and derivY for chossing the right anysotropic dirrection).

Strangly enough I don't get the same result using 

textureGrad(envmap, l_g, derivX, derivY);

and

textureLod(envmap, l_g, specular_level);

I would say that the scaling factor looks way over what it would need to be.

Here are screenshots [textureLod](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/hadrien.croubois/files/temp/iso-textureLod.png)  [textureGrad](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/hadrien.croubois/files/temp/iso-try-textureGrad.png)